# How do I decompose the value of 192 in the code `SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, 192)` into foreground and background color?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to understand how [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) works.

Per the definition in `consoleapi2.h`, this code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, FOREGROUND_RED| BACKGROUND_BLUE);
    printf("  \n");
}
```

sets the foreground color of the console as red and blue for background.

this code is to examine the combined value, that is, 20.

```
printf("%d", FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
```

as the definition in `consoleapi2.h`.

```
#define FOREGROUND_RED       0x0004 // text color contains red.
#define BACKGROUND_BLUE      0x0010 // background color contains blue.
```

So far so good, I understand the code clearly until I tried the following code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, 192);
    printf("  \n");
}
```

and I got

[image]

I make up the value of 192 but I don't know how it works. How do I decompose the value into foreground and background color?

Could someone give me a clue?

Comment: The lower 4 bits describe the text color, and the upper 4 bits the background color. The bits represent (from MSB to LSB): Intensity, red, green, blue.

Comment: Thank you, plz move your comment to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wAttributes` parameter to [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) is of type [`WORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), i.e. a 16-bit unsigned integer. The lower 8 bits of the [character attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes) encode the color information.

The following diagram illustrates what the individual bits mean:

```
+===+===+===+===+===+===+===+===+
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |   bit
+===+===+===+===+===+===+===+===+
| I | R | G | B | I | R | G | B |   meaning
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  background   |  foreground   |   scope
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

RGB are the individual red-green-blue color channels. If the respective bit is set, the color channel is on, otherwise it is off. I designates the intensity. When set it selects the "bright" color, otherwise it refers to the "dark" variant.

The value 192 is `0b1100'0000` in binary. The I and R bits of the background color are set, meaning "bright red". None of the foreground color bits are set, so the foreground color is "black".